# Expressão regular para validar um campo que aceita CPF ou CNPJ

Tags: regex

Tenho um `<input>` no formulário que deve **aceitar CPF ou CNPJ**.

Utilizarei no *back-end* em PHP o valor para guardar ou no campo "**cpf**" ou no campo "**cnpj**" de uma tabela no banco de dados.

Estou usando AngularJS e **preciso de uma expressão regular** para colocar em `ng-pattern`, para aceitar apenas dados utilizáveis.

Não me interessa neste momento validar os dígitos de verificação ao final.

Quero ser um pouco flexível, permitindo ao usuário que use pontos, traço e barra se quiser, ou só números.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

## Solução:

Esta solução valida estes formatos: 00000000000, 00000000000000, 000.000.000-00, 00.000.000/0000-00 e até 000000000-00 ou 00000000/0000-00, por exemplo. Os pontos e traços são opcionais em cada uma das posições.

O que não é aceito, por exemplo: 000-000-000-00 (mas pode ser alterado conforme nota abaixo)

### *Regex:*

```
([0-9]{2}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\/]?[0-9]{4}[-]?[0-9]{2})|([0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[\.]?[0-9]{3}[-]?[0-9]{2})
```

**[Clique aqui e faça seus testes em realtime no regexpal.](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=(%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%5B%5C.%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D%5B%5C.%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D%5B%5C%2F%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%7B4%7D%5B-%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D)%7C(%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D%5B%5C.%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D%5B%5C.%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D%5B-%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D)&input=Digite%20aqui%20dentro%20e%20teste!%0A%0A193.317.238-18%0A00.000.000%2F0000-00%0A000000000-00%0A%0A%0A)**

### Explicação:

- `[0-9]{2}` Faixa de caracteres: 0 a 9, quantidade: 2 caracteres;
- `[0-9]{3}` Faixa de caracteres: 0 a 9, quantidade: 3 caracteres;
- `[0-9]{4}` Faixa de caracteres: 0 a 9, quantidade: 4 caracteres;
- `[\.]?`Um ponto, opcional. Foi usado \ no ponto, pois ele sozinho é caractere especial;
- `[-]?` Um traço, opcional (se acrescentar outros caracteres, comece pelo - sempre);
- `[\/]?` Uma barra, opcional. Tambem "escapada" com `\` pra agradar o *PCRE*;
- `(grupo1)|(grupo2)` Se um dos grupos validar, a expressão é válida.

> Caso queira aceitar outros separadores, basta acrescentar entre os `[ ]`.
> Exemplo: `[-\.\/]?` vai aceitar tanto `-` quanto `.` e `/` naquela posição (`?` = ou nada).

Para adaptar para outros contextos de *regexp*, algumas variações possíveis seriam tirar o escape da barra (`\/` => `/`) e opcionalmente colocar um `^` no começo e um `$` no fim da linha.

Nota: propositalmente usamos `[0-9]` em vez de `\d` para que não sejam aceitos outros sets considerados dígitos (como `¹²³` e outras "surpresas" que, por exemplo, o Unicode pode trazer no futuro).

Comment: Esta minha pergunta foi feita somente porque, ao pesquisar no Google, os resultados apresentados eram medonhos. Eu pretendia postar a minha resposta logo em seguida, mas você foi hiper-veloz em responder - e forneceu uma resposta boa e correta (e sem ser *copy/paste* de pesquisa Google). Hoje, enfim, postei minha resposta, apenas relatando o que já estava implementado no momento da pergunta. Aceito sua resposta como a correta por merecimento, mas fica aqui o comentário para o público que a minha resposta, abaixo, está igualmente OK. Beleza? Obrigado.

Comment: E viva o Stack Overflow... que alcance o topo dos resultados no Google e as pessoas possam acessar boas respostas! :-)

Comment: @J.Bruni quando for assim deixe um recado no comment da pergunta, assim a gente tem como saber que já tem resposta engatilhada. (depois deleto esse comment aqui). Grato pela consideração. De fato, eu montei o regex na hora mesmo, nem me aventurei a procurar, por ser uma coisa bem específica.

Comment: mais simples: `CNPJ_REGEXP=/^(\d{2}\.?\d{3}\.?\d{3}\/?\d{4}-?\d{2})$/`

Comment: @FernandoFabreti procurei fazer ela mais didática e legivel, mas é bom o pessoal saber da versão com \d. (geralmente o parser transforma as duas versoes na mesma coisa).  Só não sei como vai ficar fica o \d com dígitos não arábicos à medida que o suporte de unicode se ampliar, e podem passar outras coisas "esquisitas" pra finalidade.

Comment: Ahh, entendi. Blz.

Comment: @Bacco Sugiro também acrescentar o ^ e $ para evitar o match quando o usuário digita, por exemplo, 12, 13 ou 15 dígitos. Aliás, acrescentei uma resposta com look behind e look ahead, para o caso do CPF ou CNPJ poder aparecer no meio do texto.

Comment: @PauloMerson eu já havia mencionado no fim da resposta. Depois, se for o caso elaboro melhor pra evidenciar o ponto. Grato pela dica, de qq forma.

Comment: sem falar que tem a opção de responder a própria pergunta assim que posta

Answer (score 25):

#### Expressão regular para validar um campo que aceita CPF ou CNPJ (sem cálculo dos dígitos verificadores):

```
/^([0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\-?[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{2}\.?[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\/?[0-9]{4}\-?[0-9]{2})$/
```

Ela pode ser entendida assim (onde "cpf" é a expressão para validar CPF e "cnpj" é a expressão para validar CNPJ):

```
/^(cpf|cnpj)$/
```

As barras inicial e final (`/`) não fazem parte da expressão propriamente dita - são apenas delimitadores. O caracter `^` no começo e o caracter `$` no final exigem que o conteúdo completo do `string` a ser validado corresponda à expressão entre os mesmos. Os parênteses contendo a barra vertical `(a|b)` criam uma "opção" alternativa entre "`a`" e "`b`". Satisfazendo qualquer uma das duas expressões, o resultado será positivo. No lugar de "`a`" e "`b`", temos então as expressões específicas para CPF e CNPJ, separadamente.

Para CPF:

```
[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\-?[0-9]{2}
```

A interrogação (`?`) faz com que a especificação de caractere precedente seja **opcional**. Portanto os pontos e o tracinho são opcionais. A classe de caracteres `[0-9]` representa qualquer caracter de `0` a `9` (poderíamos usar `\d`, mas eu prefiro `[0-9]` por ser mais legível). Finalmente, o número entre colchetes (`{3}`) determina uma quantidade específica de vezes que a especificação de caractere precedente deve se repetir. Assim sendo, são requeridos no total 11 caracteres numéricos (3 + 3 + 3 + 2).

Para CNPJ, a estrutura é semelhante:

```
[0-9]{2}\.?[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\/?[0-9]{4}\-?[0-9]{2}
```

Aqui são requeridos no total 14 caracteres numéricos (2 + 3 + 3 + 4 + 2).

Lembrando que a barra invertida (`\`) antes do ponto (`.`) e outros  caracteres especiais é um caracter de "escape", que serve para desconsiderar a interpretação especial do caractere seguinte e considerá-lo literalmente. (O ponto, sem "escape", significa "qualquer caractere". Com "escape", significa meramente o caractere "ponto" mesmo.)

---

#### Para saber se é CPF ou CNPJ

No lado do servidor, em PHP, é feita a seleção entre CPF ou CNPJ considerando o número de dígitos presentes no campo:

```
$numeros = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $valor);

if (strlen($numeros) == 11)
{
    $cliente->cpf = $valor;
}
elseif (strlen($numbers) == 14)
{
    $cliente->cnpj = $valor;
}
```

*Observação*: isso não substitui a validação feita pela expressão regular que vimos acima, a qual também é realizada no lado do servidor (no meu caso as regras estão embutidas no modelo, com as mesmas expressões regulares de validação que vimos acima para CPF e CNPJ, só que separadas - cada qual em seu respectivo campo).

Answer (score 3):

Para um input simples (permite digitar apenas CPF ou CNPJ):

```
^(\d{2}\.?\d{3}\.?\d{3}\/?\d{4}-?\d{2}|\d{3}\.?\d{3}\.?\d{3}-?\d{2})$
```

Para um input ou text box em que o CPF ou CNPJ pode aparecer no início, meio ou fim de um texto:

```
(?<=\D|^)(\d{2}\.?\d{3}\.?\d{3}\/?\d{4}-?\d{2}|\d{3}\.?\d{3}\.?\d{3}-?\d{2})(?=\D|$)
```

*A diferença principal é o uso de "look behind" e "look ahead" para garantir que o dígitos do CPF ou CNPJ são precedidos/sucedidos por caracteres não numéricos. Sem isso, haveria o match de uma sequência de, por exemplo, 20 dígitos!*

Answer (score -5):

E-mail: `"^([-a-zA-Z0-9_-]*@(gmail|yahoo|ymail|rocketmail|bol|hotmail|live|msn|ig|globomail|oi|pop|inteligweb|r7|folha|zipmail).(com|info|gov|net|org|tv)(.[-a-z]{2})?)*$"`

CPF: `"^((\d{3}).(\d{3}).(\d{3})-(\d{2}))*$"`

CNPJ: `"^((\d{2}).(\d{3}).(\d{3})/(\d{4})-(\d{2}))*$"`

CPF/CNPF:`"^(((\d{3}).(\d{3}).(\d{3})-(\d{2}))?((\d{2}).(\d{3}).(\d{3})/(\d{4})-(\d{2}))?)*$"`

Ex.: (VB.NET)

```
Dim hRegex As Regex = New Regex("^(((\d{3}).(\d{3}).(\d{3})-(\d{2}))?((\d{2}).(\d{3}).(\d{3})/(\d{4})-(\d{2}))?)*$", RegexOptions.None)

MsgBox(hRegex.IsMatch($"000.000.000-00")) 'Saída {True|False}
```

Comment: Fábio, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/277479/edit) sua resposta e para formatar o código aperte `CTRL+K`.