# Validar se entrada é realmente CNPJ

Tags: php

Estou com um formulário e preciso bloquear a entrada de CPF neste.

```
    <div id="document" class="form-group">
       <input type="text" name="document"  class="form-control" placeholder="CNPJ da Empresa" />
       <label for="document" class="text-danger">Informe um documento válido</label>
       <i class="fa fa-2x form-control-feedback"></i>
    </div>
```

a partir desta form, a informação é enviada para página de registro que recebe da seguinte forma:

```
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  $document = addslashes($_POST["document"]);
```

O meu problema é: como bloquear a entrada de CPF se possível no form ainda?

tentei fazer um strlen para verificar se o tamanho é maior que 11 (quantidade de números do CPF), porém ele sempre traz o retorno como 0 (zero).

```
if (strlen(document) > 11) {
  $document = addslashes($_POST["document"]);
}
```

ajuda por favor

Atenciosamente

Comment: [Expressão regular para validar um campo que aceita CPF ou CNPJ](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11045/91) e [outras](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=cpf+cnpj)

Comment: Para o php o que chega, são os `<input>` que estão dentro de um form e possuem o atributo `name` id não vai para o php, a menos que esteja usando JS.

Comment: Aff respondi todo o paranauê, mas esqueci de perguntar. Cadê o `form`? Não tem no código. Não seria esse o problema?

Comment: desculpe, não coloquei.

<form action="register.php" role="form" method="post" name="name" >

Answer (score 2):

## Bibloteca PHP para Validação

Uma boa biblioteca para se fazer ta validação é a `Respect\Validation`.

## Validação em Javascript

Outra opção é utilizar a função gerada pelo próprio site do `Gerador de CNPJ`. Só que está em javascript

http://www.geradorcnpj.com/javascript-validar-cnpj.htm

```
function validarCNPJ(cnpj) {
 
    cnpj = cnpj.replace(/[^\d]+/g,'');
 
    if(cnpj == '') return false;
     
    if (cnpj.length != 14)
        return false;
 
    // Elimina CNPJs invalidos conhecidos
    if (cnpj == "00000000000000" || 
        cnpj == "11111111111111" || 
        cnpj == "22222222222222" || 
        cnpj == "33333333333333" || 
        cnpj == "44444444444444" || 
        cnpj == "55555555555555" || 
        cnpj == "66666666666666" || 
        cnpj == "77777777777777" || 
        cnpj == "88888888888888" || 
        cnpj == "99999999999999")
        return false;
         
    // Valida DVs
    tamanho = cnpj.length - 2
    numeros = cnpj.substring(0,tamanho);
    digitos = cnpj.substring(tamanho);
    soma = 0;
    pos = tamanho - 7;
    for (i = tamanho; i >= 1; i--) {
      soma += numeros.charAt(tamanho - i) * pos--;
      if (pos < 2)
            pos = 9;
    }
    resultado = soma % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - soma % 11;
    if (resultado != digitos.charAt(0))
        return false;
         
    tamanho = tamanho + 1;
    numeros = cnpj.substring(0,tamanho);
    soma = 0;
    pos = tamanho - 7;
    for (i = tamanho; i >= 1; i--) {
      soma += numeros.charAt(tamanho - i) * pos--;
      if (pos < 2)
            pos = 9;
    }
    resultado = soma % 11 < 2 ? 0 : 11 - soma % 11;
    if (resultado != digitos.charAt(1))
          return false;
           
    return true;
    
}
```

Talvez você queira dar uma refatorada nesse `javascript` aí se tiver uma noção melhor de javascript.

## Validação em PHP

Aqui segue uma função para validar `cnpj`em PHP:

```
function validar_cnpj($cnpj)
{
    $cnpj = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', (string) $cnpj);
    // Valida tamanho
    if (strlen($cnpj) != 14)
        return false;
    // Valida primeiro dígito verificador
    for ($i = 0, $j = 5, $soma = 0; $i < 12; $i++)
    {
        $soma += $cnpj{$i} * $j;
        $j = ($j == 2) ? 9 : $j - 1;
    }
    $resto = $soma % 11;
    if ($cnpj{12} != ($resto < 2 ? 0 : 11 - $resto))
        return false;
    // Valida segundo dígito verificador
    for ($i = 0, $j = 6, $soma = 0; $i < 13; $i++)
    {
        $soma += $cnpj{$i} * $j;
        $j = ($j == 2) ? 9 : $j - 1;
    }
    $resto = $soma % 11;
    return $cnpj{13} == ($resto < 2 ? 0 : 11 - $resto);
}
```

Fonte: https://gist.github.com/guisehn/3276302

Comment: não usem essa solução, esta super desatualizada e alguns cnpjs não irão validar.

Comment: Tem a resposta atualizada? Se tiver, pode responder aqui para a gente.