# Campo CPF, CNPJ e Outro Documento - validação jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho um campo onde pode ser escrito o CPF, CNPJ e Outro Documento. O campo está sem máscara, enquanto o "Outro Documento" pode ser qualquer número ou letra.

Como posso fazer essas validações em `jQuery`? Verificar se o usuário digitou sem máscara ou com máscara e/ou se é um documento.

Comment: [Nessa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15707/4808) tem um exemplo de como saber se foi inserido o CPF ou CNPJ. Basta adaptar pra Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só vai conseguir fazer isso quando o cursos sair do campo, antes disso não tem como você prever o que será inserido: CPF, CNPJ ou Outro Documento.

Eu faria assim:
No `onblur` - saída do campo - pegaria o conteúdo do texto, filtraria apenas os números e se tiver 11 dígitos formataria como CPF, se tiver 14 como CNPJ, senão, não formataria.

Comment: ok, obrigado por responder

Comment: @Furlan, se satisfez, por favor, marque como resposta para sua pergunta. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Parece-me pela tua descrição que qualquer string que contenha numeros ou letras é válida. Nesse caso basta um match simples:

```
var valido = this.value.match(/^[\d\w]+$/);
```

Exemplo:

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var res = document.getElementById('res');
input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    var valido = this.value.match(/^[\d\w]+$/);
    res.innerHTML = valido ? 'valido' : 'invalido';
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="escreve algo aqui...">
<div id="res"></div>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g5o1gp45/

Comment: muito bom @Sergio, como posso remover todos os caracteres especiais, usando o mesmo Regex que vc fez quando ele mudar o valor do campo, ou seja, "onchange"

Comment: @Furlan podes dar um exemplo do que deve ser modificado? queres dizer ir tirando os `-` entre os numeros?

Comment: sim, o " . " tbm

Comment: @Furlan é isto que procuras? -> https://jsfiddle.net/g5o1gp45/1/

Comment: nao exatamente, preciso que no evento "onchange" ele remova todos os caracteres especiais, permitindo apenas letras e numeros

Comment: @Furlan :) a mudança nesse caso é minima, e acho que sabes fazer :) -> https://jsfiddle.net/g5o1gp45/2/

Answer (score 1):

Existe um plugin para jQuery que é muito conhecido chamado [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) que facilita bastante processos de validação utilizando jQuery. Você pode dar uma olhada na documentação deles para aprender como utilizar, [aqui o link](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/).