# Validar CPF com Expressão Regular JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Galera, estou tentando validar CPF apenas com Expressões regulares..
Eu já consegui validar o formato... 000.000.000-10

```
^([0-9]){3}\.([0-9]){3}\.([0-9]){3}-([0-9]){2}$
```

Agora, será que há um meio de validar se o CPF é valido em relação aos digitos verificadores?

Se possível, como?

Grato...

Comment: Você quer verificar se o CPF é válido através da expressão regular? Se for isso, é a primeira vez que vejo alguém querendo fazer isso. Normalmente a expressão regular serve para retirar mascaras. mas da uma olhada [Nesse Link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11045/express%C3%A3o-regular-para-validar-um-campo-que-aceita-cpf-ou-cnpj?rq=1), pode ter o que vc procura.

Comment: Mesmo fazer uma simples soma aritmética usando expressões regulares seria excruciantemente difícil, quanto mais validar o dígito verificador, que exige multiplicação e divisão. Eu chutaria que é possível por ser um número fixo de dígitos, mas seria uma expressão regular tão complexa que só poderia ser gerada por computador, e não passaria de uma curiosidade. Existem algumas tarefas que são conceituamente simples em expressões regulares, como determinar se um número é primo, porém nada eficientes, servem apenas para provar certas teorias a respeito de computação.

Comment: Isto chama-se golden hammer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cara não tem como validar CPF com regex porque tem conta envolvida, não é só validar a mascara.

Usa essa função ou qualquer outra que encontrar, mas regex você não vai conseguir.

```
function validarCPF(inputCPF){
    var soma = 0;
    var resto;
    var inputCPF = document.getElementById('cpf').value;

    if(inputCPF == '00000000000') return false;
    for(i=1; i<=9; i++) soma = soma + parseInt(inputCPF.substring(i-1, i)) * (11 - i);
    resto = (soma * 10) % 11;

    if((resto == 10) || (resto == 11)) resto = 0;
    if(resto != parseInt(inputCPF.substring(9, 10))) return false;

    soma = 0;
    for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++) soma = soma + parseInt(inputCPF.substring(i-1, i))*(12-i);
    resto = (soma * 10) % 11;

    if((resto == 10) || (resto == 11)) resto = 0;
    if(resto != parseInt(inputCPF.substring(10, 11))) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Ok, obrigado mano....

Answer (score -5):

Eu fiz um validador de CPF e CNPJ com typescript

```ts
export class CpfCnpjUtils {
  static isCpfValid(cpf: string): boolean {
    const cpfLength = 11;
    const weights = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
    return this.isValid(cpf, cpfLength, weights);
  }

  static isCnpjValid(cnpj: string): boolean {
    const cpfLength = 14;
    const weights = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    return this.isValid(cnpj, cpfLength, weights);
  }

  static formatCpf(cpf: string): string {
    const correctDigitsLength = 11;
    const firstDotPosition = 2;
    const secondDotPosition = 5;
    const slashPosition = -1;
    const dashPosition = 8;
    return this.format(cpf, correctDigitsLength, firstDotPosition, secondDotPosition, slashPosition, dashPosition);
  }

  static formatCnpj(cnpj: string): string {
    const correctDigitsLength = 14;
    const firstDotPosition = 1;
    const secondDotPosition = 4;
    const slashPosition = 7;
    const dashPosition = 11;
    return this.format(cnpj, correctDigitsLength, firstDotPosition, secondDotPosition, slashPosition, dashPosition);
  }

  private static format(
    digits: string,
    correctDigitsLength: number,
    firstDotPosition: number,
    secondDotPosition: number,
    slashPosition: number,
    dashPosition: number
  ): string {
    const cleanDigits = this.getOnlyNumbers(digits);
    return cleanDigits
      .slice(0, correctDigitsLength)
      .split('')
      .reduce((acc, digit, idx) => {
        const result = `${acc}${digit}`;
        if (idx !== digits.length - 1) {
          if (idx === firstDotPosition || idx === secondDotPosition) {
            return `${result}.`;
          }
          if (idx === slashPosition) {
            return `${result}/`;
          }
          if (idx === dashPosition) {
            return `${result}-`;
          }
        }
        return result;
      }, '');
  }

  private static isValid(digits: string, correctDigitsLength: number, weights: number[]): boolean {
    const cleanDigits = this.getOnlyNumbers(digits);
    if (cleanDigits.length !== correctDigitsLength || this.isAllTheSameDigits(cleanDigits)) {
      return false;
    }
    const digitsWithoutChecker = cleanDigits.substring(0, correctDigitsLength - 2);
    const digitsChecker = cleanDigits.substring(correctDigitsLength - 2, correctDigitsLength);
    const calculetedChecker = this.calcChecker(digitsWithoutChecker, weights);
    return digitsChecker === calculetedChecker;
  }

  private static getOnlyNumbers(digits: string): string {
    return digits.replace(/\D/g, '');
  }

  private static isAllTheSameDigits(digits: string): boolean {
    return !digits.split('').some((digit) => digit !== digits[0]);
  }

  private static calcChecker(digits: string, weights: number[]): string {
    const digitsLength = digits.length;
    const digitsLengthWithoutChecker = weights.length - 1;

    const sum = digits.split('').reduce((acc, digit, idx) => {
      return acc + +digit * weights[digitsLength - 1 - idx];
    }, 0);
    const sumDivisionRemainder = sum % 11;
    const checker = sumDivisionRemainder < 2 ? 0 : 11 - sumDivisionRemainder;

    if (digitsLength === digitsLengthWithoutChecker) {
      return this.calcChecker(`${digits}${checker}`, weights);
    }

    return `${digits[digitsLength - 1]}${checker}`;
  }
}
```