# Ionic 3 Mascaras e Validação de CPF

Tags: angular, validação, ionic3, mask

Boa tarde pessoal, estou fazendo um app PWA com Ionic 3 e preciso inserir algumas mascaras em formulários e fazer validação do CPF do usuário. Já tentei diversas formas e libs, mas não tive sucesso em nenhuma.
Alguém poderia me sugerir um biblioteca para fazer o mask e a validação do CPF ?

Tentei usar o br-masker-ionic-3  mas não deu certo também (https://github.com/amarkes/br-masker-ionic-3)

OBS: Para validar outros campos estou utilizando o Validators com o FormBuilder do Angular 2.

[UPDATE] Conseguir fazer as máscaras com brmasker4, apenas importando a biblioteca no module da página e inserindo a validação na tag input do HTML, agora só resta fazer a validação de CPF válido

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123741/validar-cpf-com-express%C3%A3o-regular-javascript

Comment: no link acima tem o que você procura.