# Como criar pattern (mascara de input) com jQuery Validation Plugin?

Tags: jquery, regex, plugin, jquery-validate, jquery-plugins

Estou precisando criar uma **mascara de input** (pattern) para o tipo **CPF 000.000.000-00** e para **CNPJ 00.000.000/0000-00** através do plugin **jQuery Validation**. Qual seria o regex para estar criando essa validação?

Nota: CPF e CNPJ serão dois inputs diferentes.

Grato.

Comment: Você quer fazer o teste para saber se o CPF e CNPJ é valido? ou só verificar se esta neste formato? se você quer ver se é valido, não sera possível, pois segue um algoritmo de calculo por **digito verificador**. Teria de ser uma função.

Comment: Olá Guilherme, eu quero só verificar se esta nesse formato.

Answer (score 2):

Para isso você pode usar o [jQuery Mask](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.cpf').mask('000.000.000-00');
  $('.cnpj').mask('00.000.000/0000-00');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

CPF :<input type="text" class="cpf">
<br/>
CNPJ :<input type="text" class="cnpj">
```

#### Nota

- Lembrando que assim ele não verifica se é um conteúdo valido, apenas poem neste formato.

### Edit

As REGEXs para validar CPF e CNPJ poderiam ser

- CPF : `\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}-\d{2}`
- CNPJ : `\d\d\.\d{3}\.\d{3}-\d{4}-\d\d`

Veja no [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/MrUCVz/1).

Comment: Olá Guilherme, na verdade eu preciso dessa validação através desse plugin (jQuery Validation) mesmo, pois eu peguei um theme Wordpress e estou tendo que realizar algumas implementações, todas as validações e mascaras dos inputs dos formulários são feitas através desse plugin. Eu sei mais ou menos por cima como criar a função para isso, só preciso mesmo do regex para campos CPF e CNPJ.

Comment: @RodrigoFontes editado.

Comment: Veja tbm [Expressão regular para validar um campo que aceita CPF ou CNPJ](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11045/14213)