# Criar padrão de caracteres como em um CPF - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

O que quero fazer é: digitar um CPF sem pontos nem traço e depois adicionar os pontos e o traço com JS, criar um padrão. Exemplo: escrevo 99999999999 e o sistema me devolve 999.999.999-99.
Como faço isso em Javascript puro?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Expressão regular para validar um campo que aceita CPF ou CNPJ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11045/express%c3%a3o-regular-para-validar-um-campo-que-aceita-cpf-ou-cnpj)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode utilizar *Expressões Regulares*. Ex:

```
^([\d]{3})([\d]{3})([\d]{3})([\d]{2})$
 └───┬───┘└───┬───┘└───┬───┘└───┬───┘
     │        │        │        └───── Captura os dois últimos dígitos
     │        │        └────────────── Captura os valores entre 7º e 9º dígitos
     │        └─────────────────────── Captura os valores entre o 4º e 6º dígito
     └──────────────────────────────── Captura o três primeiros dígitos
```

Depois basta utilizar: `$1`, `$2`, `$3` e `$4` para capturar os grupos.

**Segue exemplo:**

```js
const cpf = document.querySelector("#cpf");

cpf.addEventListener("blur", () => {
  let value = cpf.value.replace(/^([\d]{3})([\d]{3})([\d]{3})([\d]{2})$/, "$1.$2.$3-$4");
  
  cpf.value = value;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="cpf" />
```

Você também pode utilizar o evento `keyup` para fazer isso enquanto digita o texto.

```js
const cpf = document.querySelector("#cpf");

cpf.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  let value = cpf.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "").replace(/^([\d]{3})([\d]{3})?([\d]{3})?([\d]{2})?/, "$1.$2.$3-$4");
  
  cpf.value = value;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="cpf" />
```

Comment: Estou estudando JS então esse tipo de ajuda é sensacional. Muito obrigado!

Comment: O do keyup é terrivel pra editar o numero. Neste segundo caso, recomendo deixar o usuário digitar apenas digitos, e colocar os pontos e traço somente depois (experimente digitar um caractere errado ou dois e corrigir). Mas a resposta está ok, ja levou meu +1

Comment: Tirei o syntax highligther do diagrama (não resisti e tomei a liberdade de trocar por box characters, se não gostar fique à vontade para reverter, só observe o HTML Comment que tira o colorido do trecho. (logo mais deleto este comment aqui)

Comment: Estou a um tempo procurando por regex js e não entendia como funcionava até achar essa resposta maravilhosa e mostrar como e simples!

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra forma usando regex:

```js
var cpf = document.querySelector("#cpf");

cpf.addEventListener("blur", function(){
   cpf.value = cpf.value.match(/.{1,3}/g).join(".").replace(/\.(?=[^.]*$)/,"-");
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cpf" maxlength="11" />
```

A regex `/.{1,3}/g` *quebra* a string de 3 em 3 caracteres criando uma array. o `join(".")` reajunta a array inserindo um ponto entre cada item, e o `replace` com a regex `/\.(?=[^.]*$)/` substitui o último ponto "`.`" por hífen "`-`".