# Tratar lista de CNPJ's com expressão regular

Tags: regex

OTenho uma lista de CNPJ's, gostaria de pegar essa lista e acrescentar aspas simples e separar cada um deles com vírgula, fazendo isso com expressão regular.

Ex.: 
Minha lista:

> 32132132132 32132132132 321321321323 32132132132132

Como desejo que fique:

> '32132132132','32132132132','321321321323','32132132132132'

Comment: Faltou a linguagem, os Regexs (Expressões Regulares) funcionam de maneira diferente dependendo da Linguagem

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Expressão regular para validar um campo que aceita CPF ou CNPJ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11045/express%c3%a3o-regular-para-validar-um-campo-que-aceita-cpf-ou-cnpj)

Comment: Eu faria algo do tipo: [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8UXZhq/1), que funcionaria em alguns dos editores de texto mais simples... A sua pergunta seria mais para substituir numa lista que possui o espaço como separador, para vírgula como separador e colocar apóstrofe delimitando cada elemento. E não tratar CNPJ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sinceramente não vejo motivo para utilizar *Expressões Regulares* em algo simples.

Em *PHP* utilize [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) e [`join`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.join.php)

```
$str = '32132132132 32132132132 321321321323 32132132132132';
$exp = explode(' ', $str);
echo "'" . join("';'", $exp) . "'";
```

> Veja funcionando em [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ContentExternalInverse)

Em *Python* utilize [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) e [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join)

```
str = '32132132132 32132132132 321321321323 32132132132132';
exp = str.split();
print("'" + "';'".join(exp) + "'")
```

> Veja funcionando em [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/MellowCrimsonTrees)

Em *Java* utilize [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) e [`join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-)

```
String link = "32132132132 32132132132 321321321323 32132132132132";
String[] partes = link.split(" ");
System.out.println("'" + String.join("';'", partes) + "'");
```

> Veja funcionando em [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/OrneryWorthwhileAddresses)

Em *JavaScript* utilize [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) e [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
let str = '32132132132 32132132132 321321321323 32132132132132';
let res = "'" + str.split(' ').join("';'") + "'";
console.log(res)
```